# Jackson : Read json entry (with missing fields) into a POJO

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a json entry like :

```
{
    "name" : "tom"
    "age" : 10
}
```

Some json entries have an additional field of `address`.

I'm trying to read it to a POJO defined as follows :

```
public class StudentDetails {


    @NonNull
    private final String name;

    @NonNull
    private final int age;

    private final String address;
```

I'm unable to deserialise this. What Jackson annotation can I use to accomplish this ? Some of the entries will have the field of `address` whereas others won't.

Tried using @NonNull, @Nullable, @JsonIclude, @JsonIgnoreProperities, Optional<>

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
```

This indicates that only properties with non-null values are to be included.

Comment: `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` is only effective during serialization and not during deserialization (which is what I'm interested in)